# Parsing an XML file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am having trouble parsing XML data in the JS code following it.  I have several XML row tags that I am trying to pull data from, this is just a sample.  There is a problem with the loop section in the JS code (I've never been good at loops) and I am only getting the information from the first row tag repeatedly in my sidebar.  How do I get it to read all of the row tags?

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <time>2014-11-05T10:53:35.757Z</time>
    <latitude>41.896</latitude>
    <longitude>-119.6168</longitude>
    <depth>1.6069</depth>
    <mag>2.87</mag>
    <magType>ml</magType>
    <nst>4</nst>
    <gap>145.83</gap>
    <dmin>0.511</dmin>
    <rms>0.1222</rms>
    <net>nn</net>
    <id>nn00466295</id>
    <updated>2014-11-05T11:48:11.391Z</updated>
    <place>68km ESE of Lakeview, Oregon</place>
    <type>earthquake</type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <time>2014-11-05T10:30:37.000Z</time>
    <latitude>60.366</latitude>
    <longitude>-151.8877</longitude>
    <depth>70</depth>
    <mag>2.5</mag>
    <magType>ml</magType>
    <nst/>
    <gap/>
    <dmin/>
    <rms/>
    <net>ak</net>
    <id>ak11434200</id>
    <updated>2014-11-05T11:53:47.658Z</updated>
    <place>32km W of Cohoe, Alaska</place>
    <type>earthquake</type>
  </row>
  .
  .
  .
</rows>




<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Final Project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        #title      { font-size: 30px }
        .side_table { height:515px; overflow:auto; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var markers = [];

      function myclick(num) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[num], "click");
      }

      function createMarker(point,info,map) {
        var iconURL = 'cone.png';               var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(20,34);
        var iconOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0,0);    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(10,34);

        var myIcon = {
          url: iconURL, 
          size: iconSize, 
          origin: iconOrigin, 
          anchor: iconAnchor
        };

        var iconShape = [8,33, 4,15, 1,15, 0,12, 0,5, 6,0, 12,0, 19,14, 15,15, 10,33];
        var myMarkerShape = {
          coord: iconShape,
          type: 'poly'
        };

        var myMarkerOpts = {
          position: point,
          map: map,
          icon: myIcon,
          shape: myMarkerShape
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOpts);

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infoWindow.close();
          infoWindow.setContent(info);
          infoWindow.open(map,marker); 
        });
      } 

    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

      var mapOpts = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOpts);

    downloadUrl("csv2xml.php", function(data) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(data);
                var records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");
                var side_html = '<div class="side_table"> \
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" \
                        cellpadding="5"> \
                        <thead> \
                            <tr style="background-color:#e0e0e0"> \
                            <th>Location</th> \
                            <th>Magnitude</th> \
                            </tr> \
                        </thead> \
                        <tbody>';


    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    var rec = records[i];

                    var time = records[0].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var lat = parseFloat(records[0].getElementsByTagName("latitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    var lng = parseFloat(records[0].getElementsByTagName("longitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    var depth = records[0].getElementsByTagName("depth")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var mag = records[0].getElementsByTagName("mag")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var id = records[0].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var updated = records[0].getElementsByTagName("updated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var place = records[0].getElementsByTagName("place")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                    var row = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                    //Infowindow parameters
                    var html = "<strong>Location: </strong>" + place + "<br />" +
                                "<strong>Magnitude: </strong>" + mag + "<br />" +
                                "<strong>Depth: </strong>" + depth + "<br />" +
                                "<strong>Time: </strong>" + time + "<br />";

                    //Sidebar parameters
                    side_html += '<tr> \
                                    <td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + place + '</a></td> \
                                    <td>' + mag + '</td> \
                                </tr>';

                    createMarker(row,html,map);
                }

                side_html += '</tbody> \
                          </table>';
                document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_html;
            });
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="title" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:5px;"><b>RealTime Earthquakes Greater Than 2.5 Magnitude Over The Last Day</b></div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px"></div>
        <div id="side_bar" style="width: 200px; height 500px; position: absolute; left: 1030px; top: 40px"></div>
        <div id="notes" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:550px; width:95%">
            <u>Final Project Reflection</u><br>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: from your code you get just the first row because your getting just the fist one [0] !! change  records[0] -->  rec

Comment: Please create a trimmed-down version of your code no longer than 50 lines, ideally 20. Then people might find the time to look at it. As a bonus, while doing that you'll probably find the problem yourself.

Comment: As nasser nearly wrote, instead of `var time = records[0]...` try `var time = records[i]...`.

Comment: I did try that before posting this, but I replaced all of the [0] with [i].  Now I see you are only supposed to use [i] after records and not all of them.  Thanks nasser and RobG!!  Works as I wanted now.